# Spring boot for Spring mvc and Angular JS not refreshing static resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running Spring boot in IntelliJ idea and have found that spring boot is no longer refreshing my changes to the resources which is where i have the html and js files. It was working fine but now only seems to detect changes on system reboot.

Is there a way to prevent caching of files ?

Answer (score 0):

let assume you cached the required files like below code :

@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
@Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webConfigurer () {
      return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
              registry.addResourceHandler("/static/js/**")
                      .addResourceLocations("/static/js/")
                      .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(300, TimeUnit.DAYS));
              registry.addResourceHandler("/static/images/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/static/images/")
              .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(7, TimeUnit.DAYS));
              registry.addResourceHandler("/static/css/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/static/css/")
              .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(300, TimeUnit.DAYS));
          }
      };
  }
```

}

add new folder like "nonCached" folder and include your non Cached files like below :
[image]